# sort a list of characters using lambdas in java

Tags: java, java-stream

ok this is homework. I have tried a couple things but just cant get it to work. the instructions are--Write a program that inserts 30 random letters
into a List. Perform the following operations and display your results:
a) Sort the List in ascending order.
b) Sort the List in descending order.
c) Display the List in ascending order with duplicates removed. I have the simplest part done but when it comes to the sorting im not sure where to start. 
    public class RandomCharacters {

// private static List randomCharacters;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    //Create List of Char type
    List<Character> randomCharacters = new ArrayList<>();
    //Character[] randChars = new Character[30];

    //generate random letters and add to the list
    for(int i = 0; i<30; i++){
        int num = (int) (26* Math.random());
        //randChars[i] = (char) (num + 'a');
        char letter = (char) (num + 'a');
        randomCharacters.add(letter);
        //System.out.println(letter);
    }
    //System.out.println( "Unsorted list= " + Arrays.asList(randChars));
    System.out.println( "Unsorted list= " + randomCharacters);


    System.out.println("Ascending sort: ");
    Arrays  .stream(randomCharacters)
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I have tried doing it two ways. one with the Character Array and converting that using tolist and by just using the ArrayList but the sort is not working. any hints as to why this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright thanks guys i used a combination of both of your soulutions and here is my complete code. I think its good for what i need but if anyone thinks it can be more efficent let me know 
    public class RandomCharacters {

```
private static List<Character> randomCharacters;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    //Create List of Char type
    List<Character> randomCharacters = new ArrayList<>();


    //generate random letters and add to the list
    for(int i = 0; i<30; i++){
        int num = (int) (26* Math.random());
        char letter = (char) (num + 'a');
        randomCharacters.add(letter);
    }

    System.out.println( "Unsorted list= " + randomCharacters);

    List<Character> sortedList = randomCharacters.stream()
                                                 .sorted()
                                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("Ascending sort: " + sortedList);


    List<Character> reversedList = randomCharacters.stream()
                                                    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("Sorted Descending: " + reversedList);

    List<Character> uniqueList = randomCharacters.stream()
                                                 .sorted()
                                                 .distinct()
                                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("Unique Sort: "+ uniqueList);
}
```

}

i will add more comments before turning in as well

Answer (score 5):

You can call [`Stream.sorted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--) and [`Stream.sorted(Comparator<? super T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) and [`Stream.distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--). Something like,

```
System.out.println("Unsorted list= " + randomCharacters);
System.out.println("Sorted Ascending: ");
randomCharacters.stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println("Sorted Descending: ");
randomCharacters.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println("Ascending unique sort: ");
randomCharacters.stream().sorted().distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: awesome ok. i did it like the other answer below but i see how this one works too. actually i feel like this works better however when it prints it just prints each letter on a new line and i think it should print it as a list (eg[a,b,c,d,so on]. also so instead of doing Arrays.stream i use randomCharacter.stream. Thank you for your help i appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

Because you call ".collect" on the stream but don't store it anywhere. And you print the unsorted list (you are sorting the list after printing it).
Do this instead

```
List<Character> sortedList = randomCharacters.stream()
                                             .sorted()
                                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Ascending sort: " + sortedList);
```

Comment: perfect thank you. Now i understand what my problem was. i was calling collect but it was not "saving" to anything so i needed to create the sortedList list to call later that has the collection. now for part b i will just use the .reversed and for part c i will use a map! Thanks!

Comment: oh and i was printing out the list before i sorted it! that was silly