# How do you sort a string with lambda expressions in Java?

Tags: java, string, lambda

I'm just learning about lambda expressions and I was wondering how to return a sorted string. For example, if I have "cba", I want "abc". Normally I would do:

```
String s = "cba";
char[] charList = s.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(charList);
String sorted = charList.toString();
```

is there a way to do that in one line with lambda expressions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21970805/4828463

Comment: or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36255014/4828463

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this like that:

```
final String s = "cba";
final String collect = Arrays.stream(s.split(""))
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IntStream` from `String.chars()`

```
    "cba"
            .chars()
            .sorted()
            .mapToObj(value -> (char) value)
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString()
```